# Draw graphics from DataTable and get the possibility to change the scale dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, charts, datatable, scale

i need your help, actually i got a DataTable with 9 columns. The first is the date and after is value from 8 differents sensors. I need to draw these graphics and especially i need to can change the scale of AxyY dynamically (it's a date in this format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Actually i do it like that, i can only draw 1 curves but it's ok, i juste really need to can change scale like i want :

```
    chart1.DataSource = DTTrendsChart;
chart1.Series.Add("Capteur1");
chart1.Titles.Clear();
chart1.Titles.Add(NomCapteur).Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);

chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = UnitéCapteur[i];
                    
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Date";
chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Date"; // Date from the first column
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Field_2"; //name of the 2 column (value from the 2 sensor)
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Hoping you can help me ! Have a great day guys !

Comment: I want to can change the scale but if i can zoom on the chart dynamically it's also good.

Comment: [Zooming a Chart Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+zoom)

Comment: Thank you ! it work, i juste get the code from the first post. I got another problem, i don't now if you can help me but when i want to see the AxeX value of the first point and the last point on my axe but i didn't see it, i got this : https://ibb.co/chgMVNp

Comment: Looks like there is not enough room; maybe you could set the labels to display at an angle or you could set the minimum further to the left.

Comment: With `Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;`either `ax.LabelStyle.Format = "YYYY.MMddD \nhh:mm:ss,ffff";` (note the newline charavter!!) or `ax.LabelStyle.Angle  = 90;` could help

Comment: Thanks for the labelStyle it's better now but i still have my problem : i got this now : https://ibb.co/whQNFqc but i didn't get the first value of Axis X, if i zoom on the chart i can see it but i want to see without zoom : https://ibb.co/8bYzJVj

Comment: There are various tweaks yu can try, e.g. `ax.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
ax.Interval = 1;` or you can play with the IntervalOffset. Note that intervals are always evently spaced!